# XUL. Tree.Why sub-items drops?

Tags: javascript, json, tree, firefox-addon, xul

I have a XUL tree, which will contain some dynamic JSON tree.

I Have JSON(Generated by my Win app):

```
{
    "Description": "",
    "id": "0x7183D2AD",
    "Name": "",
    "Children": [{
        "Description": "",
        "id": "0x660452D5",
        "Name": "Bookmarks menu",
        "Children": [{
            "Description": "",
            "id": "0x32DD7955",
            "Name": "Mozilla Firefox",
            "Children": []
        }]
    },
    {
        "Description": "",
        "id": "0x10EFAAFD",
        "Name": "Bookmarks panel",
        "Children": [{
            "Description": "",
            "id": "0x2542B587",
            "Name": "123",
            "Children": []
        }]
    },
    {
        "Description": "",
        "id": "0x39AD4290",
        "Name": "Tags",
        "Children": []
    },
    {
        "Description": "",
        "id": "0x464248E7",
        "Name": "unassigned bookmarks",
        "Children": []
    }]
```

I want fill the XUL tree by this data & realize structure(for example: this JSON ^^):

- Bookmarks menu
- - Mozilla Firefox
- Bookmarks panel
- - 123
- Tags
- Unassigned bookmarks

I wrote JS recursive functions:

```
    JOToTreeNode: function(RootEl,JO) {
        var ti = document.createElementNS(XUL_NS,'treeitem');
        ti.setAttribute("id",JO.id);
        var tr = document.createElementNS(XUL_NS,'treerow');
        ti.appendChild(tr);
        var tc1 = document.createElementNS(XUL_NS,'treecell');
        var tc2 = document.createElementNS(XUL_NS,'treecell');
        tc1.setAttribute("label",JO.Name);
        tc2.setAttribute("label",JO.Description);
        tr.appendChild(tc1);
        tr.appendChild(tc2);        
        if (JO.Children.length > 0) {
            var child = document.createElementNS(XUL_NS,"treechildren");
            ti.appendChild(child);
            for (var i = 0; i < JO.Children.length; i++) {
             UtilCommon.JOToTreeNode(child,JO.Children[i]);    
            }
        };
        RootEl.appendChild(ti);
    }
...
    UpdateTree: function(el) {
        var els = el.getElementsByTagName("treechildren");
        //Drop the previous tree
            if(els.length > 0) {el.removeChild(els[0])};
        //Get JSON tree of groups
        var  http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open("GET","http://"+this.host+":"+this.port+"/jsfolderstree",false);
        http.send(null);
        if (http.status == 200) { 
            var jtree = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
            var child = document.createElementNS(XUL_NS,"treechildren");
            el.appendChild(child);
            for (var i = 0; i < jtree.Children.length; i++) {
             UtilCommon.JOToTreeNode(child,jtree.Children[i]);
            };

    };
  }
```

It works, but the tree contains only first level of nodes, e.g.:

```
 - Bookmarks menu
 - Bookmarks panel
 - Tags
 - Unassigned bookmarks
```

If I place code:

```
alert(JO.Name);
```

in UtilCommon.JOToTreeNode, I will see, that the sub-items like "123" and "Mozilla firefox" are exists, but doesn't add to tree as sub-items.

Where my mistake, how I can fix bug when sub-items doesn't attaches to the tree?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [tree-XUL documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/XUL/tree#A_tree_with_several_columns_and_nested_items), you should set the `container=true` for nested tree-items

```
...
if (JO.Children.length > 0) {
    ti.setAttribute("container", true);
    var child = document.createElementNS(XUL_NS,"treechildren");
    ti.appendChild(child);
    for (var i = 0; i < JO.Children.length; i++) {
       UtilCommon.JOToTreeNode(child,JO.Children[i]);    
    }
};
...
```